# Can Ansible be configured to try multiple SSH keys?

Tags: ssh, ansible

I understand that when running an SSH command with public key authentication, the client will try all the SSH keys it knows about until the host accepts one (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/182804/how-does-ssh-know-which-public-key-to-use-from-authorized-keys).

When running an Ansible command on a host using SSH there does not seem to be this capability: Ansible requires an SSH private key file to be specified explicitly in ansible.cfg:

```
private_key_file = /user/.ssh/id_rsa_mykey
```

In my use case, Ansible is running inside a docker container on Lando. All SSH keys are imported from the user's ssh config directory to a known path in the container. However, I don't necessarily know the name of the one that's needed by Ansible because this is something individual users configure.

Is there a way to make SSH commands issued by Ansible try multiple keys like SSH is designed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ansible requires an SSH private key file to be specified explicitly in ansible.cfg:

Ansible does *not* require that you provide a private key file in your `ansible.cfg`. Since `ansible` is just calling out to `ssh`, the preferred place to configure connection credentials is in your `~/.ssh/config` file. There, you can configure multiple host-specific keys:

```
Host host1
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key-for-host1

Host host2
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key-for-host2
```

Or you can configure it to try multiple keys in sequence:

```
Host *.example.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/maybe-this-one
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/okay-how-about-this-instead
```

And of course `ssh` will use any keys present in your ssh agent.

Comment: Thanks @larsks. However, if I don't specify a private key file in `ansible.cfg` and I don't specify an `IdentifyFile` in `~/.ssh/config` either, then issuing an ssh command on its own (without Ansible) will try all keys in `~/.ssh/` until it finds one that works. This is what I want to achieve with Ansible. I can't try multiple keys in sequence because the keys could be named anything. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't believe `ssh` behaves like that. If you have keys with arbitrary names in `~/.ssh`, ssh isn't going to discover and use them unless explicitly instructed to do so. Your best bet may just to to load all the keys you want into your ssh agent.